# User name regex not working when checking for length

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate user names, in Java, based on the following rules:

- must start with lowercase alpha (a-z)
- subsequent characters can be lowercase alpha (a-z) or digits (0-9)
- Only one symbol, period "." may be used, only once and cannot be at the start or end of the user name

The regex I am using to perform validation is `^[a-z]+\.?[a-z0-9]+$`

This works quite nice (there may be better ways of doing this), except now I want to allow user names that are between 3 and 10 characters long. Anywhere I try to use `{3,10}`, e.g. `^([a-z]+\.?[a-z0-9]+){3,10}$`, validation fails. I am using an excellent [visual regex tool](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5C.%3F%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%29%7B3%2C10%7D%24) and [online regex tester](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

The code itself is really simple; I am using the String class' [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) method in Java 8. *john.doe* passes the regex and length validation, but *j.doe* does not.

**Update, based on selected answer:**

The Java code can be a little self-explanatory, given the complexity of the regex:

```
private static final String PATTERN_USERNAME_REGEX = new StringBuilder()
    // the string should contain 3 to 10 chars
    .append("(?=.{3,10}$)")
    // the string should start with a lowercase ASCII letter
    .append("[a-z]")
    // then followed by zero or more lowercase ASCII letters or/and digits
    .append("[a-z0-9]*")
    // an optional sequence of a period (".") followed with 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters
    // or/and digits (that + means you can't have . at the end of the string and ? guarantees
    // the period can only appear once in the string)
    .append("(?:\\\\.[a-z0-9]+)?")
    .toString();
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't seem correct. It wouldn't match `a0.1`.

Comment: Don't check the length in the regex, do it separately and first so you don't bother doing the regex at all if the length is out of range... `if (uid.length() >= 3 && uid.length() <=10 && regex.matches(...)) ...`  This will be easier for someone else to understand and maintain.

Comment: @shmosel the length-agnostic first regex will work. The second one does not, which I know is incorrect and thereby unreliable.

Comment: @JimGarrison that is something I considered and glad to have that thought validated by others! :-)

Comment: Are you saying it shouldn't match? Why not?

Comment: @shmosel which regex are you referring to, by the way?

Comment: The first one: `^[a-z]+\.?[a-z0-9]+$`

Comment: @shmosel aah, yes, `[a-z]+` will not allow "a0" at the start. Guess I need to go back to the basics on regex! That first regex should have been `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*\.?[a-z0-9]+$`, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you seek is

```
^(?=.{3,10}$)[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)?$
```

In Java,

```
s.matches("(?=.{3,10}$)[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:\\.[a-z0-9]+)?")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T67zbG/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (no need to use in `String#matches`)
- `(?=.{3,10}$)` - the string should contain 3 to 10 chars
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `[a-z0-9]*` zero or more lowercase ASCII letters or/and digits
- `(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.` followed with 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters or/and digits (that `+` means you can't have `.` at the end of the string and `?` guarantees the `.` can only appear once in the string)
- `$` - end of string (no need to use in `String#matches`)

Comment: I already said that I hate regex from the bottom of my heart. Really, I think that the regex should be obsolete in the very future. How for Gods sake _this_ can be readable? No matter what, you get +1 from me.

Comment: @zlakad nice way to echo your sentiment while also appreciating the answer. I feel like that sometimes, although I sincerely respect and appreciate how quickly some people (like Wiktor) can quickly understand the requirement and whip out a regex in an impressively short period of time! I actually learnt something from this answer, by the way.

Comment: @WebUser very well noticed! Thanks, friend.

Comment: @WebUser It's much easier to write regex than to read it, in my experience. (True of coding in general, but especially regex.)

Comment: @shmosel well said, and totally agree!

Comment: I have a slight more difficult regex [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101311/java-based-regex-for-azure-ad-cloud-user-account-password-policy), which involves combination of permitted character classes.