# Java based Regex for Azure AD cloud user account password policy

Tags: java, regex, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement [Azure AD cloud user account policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts) in Java using regex.

I have defined a pattern string and I use [string.matches(pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) as follows:

```
// ONE OF THESE CHARACTER CLASS COMBINATIONS NEED TO BE MET
// combination of lowercase, uppercase and numbers, 8 to 16 characters in length
// combination of lowercase, uppercase and symbols, 8 to 16 characters in length
// combination of lowercase, numbers and symbols, 8 to 16 characters in length
// combination of uppercase, numbers and symbols 8 to 16 characters in length
private static final String PATTERN_PASSWORD_REGEX = new StringBuilder('^')
        .append("((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])).{8,16}")
        .append('|') // -or-
        .append("((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&*\\-_!+=\\[\\]{}|\\:‘,.?\\/`~“\\(\\);])).{8,16}")
        .append('|') // -or-
        .append("((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%^&*\\-_!+=\\[\\]{}|\\:‘,.?\\/`~“\\(\\);])).{8,16}")
        .append('|') // -or-
        .append("((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%^&*\\-_!+=\\[\\]{}|\\:‘,.?\\/`~“\\(\\);])).{8,16}")
        .append('$')
        .toString();

public static boolean validate(String password) {
    return password.matches(PATTERN_PASSWORD_REGEX);
}
```

Somehow, it is treating spaces as a special character, even though I have *not* included it in the regex. The JUnit test method below is passing on all the assertions except the last one.

```
@Test
public void testPassword() {

    Assert.assertTrue("password is valid", validate("Abcdef12"));
    Assert.assertTrue("password is valid", validate("abcde$12"));
    Assert.assertTrue("password is valid", validate("ABCDE%12"));
    Assert.assertTrue("password is valid", validate("Abcde~12"));
    Assert.assertFalse("password is invalid", validate("abcdefgh"));
    Assert.assertFalse("password is invalid", validate("12345678"));
    Assert.assertFalse("password is invalid", validate("ABCDEFGH"));
    Assert.assertFalse("password is invalid", validate("ABCDefgh"));
    Assert.assertFalse("password is invalid", validate("!~$:-_@&"));

    // This assertion fails...
    Assert.assertFalse("password is invalid", validate("Abcdef 12"));
}
```

I have seen very elegant answers for regex questions on SO, but generally they don't involve character classes combinations. Hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, or if there is a much better way of doing this.

Comment: `Abcdef 12` is matched with the `((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])).{8,16}`  part, hence it is false since `validate` returns true.

Comment: I see the problem now, my regex don't have an exclusion component, preventing disallowed character classes. It is using an inclusive pattern. Is there a better/elegant way to implement the requirement?

Comment: I will check it once my children go to bed and if I do not fall asleep earlier :) Some hour or hour and a half.

Comment: Is it worth trying to use an exclusive check first, following by an inclusive check next? In other words, maybe check if the string contains characters not in the set `a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&*-_!+=[]{}|\:‘,.?/\`~“();` and preempt the actual, inclusive check for presence of required character combinations.

Comment: Do you plan to match a string containing a space? If not, use https://regex101.com/r/LhulES/2

Comment: I want strings containing [white-]space, unicode and any other characters not in the defined set, i.e. `@#$%^&*-_!+=[]{}|\:‘,.?/\`~“();` to fail validation.

Comment: So, that means `Abcdef 12` should `assertTrue`. It is valid acc. to your *combination of lowercase, uppercase and numbers, 8 to 16 characters in length* rule.

Comment: `Abcdef 12` should `assertFalse`, since it contains _uppercase_, _lowercase_ and _numbers_, but it also contains a space that is not among the permitted characters.

Comment: Aha, so those are not just required chars, but also permitted ones. Just put them all into a char class instead of `.`. See https://regex101.com/r/LhulES/3. Replace `.{8,16}` with `[-A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&*_!+=\\[\\]{}|:',.?/\`~\"();]{8,16}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify those chars you allow in the last part, instead of the dot. Replace `.{8,16}` with `` [-A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&*_!+=\[\]{}|:',.?/`~\"();]{8,16} ``:

```
^(?:
 (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)
 |
 (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-@#$%^&*_!+=\[\]{}|:',.?/`~"();])
 |
 (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-@#$%^&*_!+=\[\]{}|:',.?/`~"();])
 |
 (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-@#$%^&*_!+=\[\]{}|:',.?/`~"();])
)
[-A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&*_!+=\[\]{}|:',.?/`~"();]{8,16}
$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LhulES/3).

```
private static final String PATTERN_PASSWORD_REGEX = new StringBuilder('^(?:')
    .append("(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])")
    .append('|') // -or-
    .append("(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=.*[-@#$%^&*_!+=\\[\\]{}|:‘,.?/`~“();])")
    .append('|') // -or-
    .append("(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=.*[-@#$%^&*_!+=\\[\\]{}|:‘,.?/`~“();])")
    .append('|') // -or-
    .append("(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=.*[-@#$%^&*_!+=\\[\\]{}|:‘,.?/`~“();])")
    .append(')[-A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&*_!+=\\[\\]{}|:‘,.?/`~“();]{8,16}$')
    .toString();
```

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor... even more so for taking the effort to update the Java method, in addition to providing a live regex demo example!